# Does Informix Support Computed / Calculated / Virtual / Derived Columns?

Tags: sql, informix, calculated-columns

I've been searching a lot (really) if Informix supports something like SQL Server Computed Columns.
The closest I've been able to get to are the functional indexes, which are able to calculate a value from the other field. But these indexes only support functions of the non-variant type (which doesn't performs select, etc).

Here's an example of a functional column in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE __msa_price_for_update (
    hpa_plan_msa        varchar(15),
    hpa_inv_desc_msa    varchar(35),
    hpa_price_1         float,
    hpa_id              int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (fn_hpa_hcpc_id(hpa_plan_msa, hpa_inv_desc_msa)) 
)
```

Obs: consider the function in the example as of the variant type (which performs select, etc).

So, does something similar exist in Informix? If yes, would be able to give examples and documentation? If it doesn't support it, is there something nearly equivalent? Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: You can just use a view.

Comment: I need the value to be stored in the database. View have a severe cost at the runtime.

Comment: No, you don't, and no, they don't.  If the value is "generated always", presumably the function is invoked every time the data is selected or otherwise exposed.  That'll happen with a view, too.

Comment: If "generated always" doesn't mean "generated every time the value is used", then what does it mean?  There are other possible ways to work things — such as triggers.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it seems like calculated columns consumes less resources once they are pre calculated by the system, while views needs to be fully calculated at every time. Please, I don't know how triggers could be manipulated to have this behavior. Because they depend on the event of an insert, update or delete. While calculated columns are always refreshed. Sorry for not comprehending.

Comment: @Gabz . . . That is true of a "stored" or "persisted" generated column.  However, the SQL Server code is not persisting the value so it is calculated when it is accessed.

Comment: When are "generated always" values generated?  When the row is changed?  When the row is selected?  Something else?  If the answer is "when the rows is changed", then triggers can be used.  If the answer is "when the row is selected", then views are fine.  If the answer is "something else", then maybe the answer is also "something else (than views and triggers)", but until you say what the behaviour you want to emulate is, it is hard to know how to emulate it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. So my intention is to have a table with a persisted value (which will not be calculated at the select time, but will already be updated before the select). So, for example, tables A and B. "A" needs a column x built over the function(B.z, A.y). Then whenever B.z or A.y changes the A.x would also be updated. I believe it's what a persisted calculated column does.

Comment: Summarizing = I need the maximum performance at the query time, so it's why the values should be pre calculated and available at it's newest version. Also, this calculation can't happen for the entire table, but just for the rows which their related values have also been changed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure it applies to Informix, but typically "generated always" -- as opposed to "generated by default" -- means that you cannot provide an explicit value in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement; if you did, that would generated an error.

Comment: @TheImpaler — Informix doesn't support the keyword GENERATED.  Your comment seems to mean that the value (of a GENERATED ALWAYS column) is set by function invocation on INSERT or UPDATE, and cannot be overridden by a user-specified value.  I think that can be achieved in Informix with triggers; the only concern I have is whether variant functions that use SELECT (etc) can be used.  I'd have to experiment.  The "cannot be overridden" part may end up requiring discipline; you can stop most users, but maybe not DBAs or the table owner.